Ошибка при запуске бота на Aiogram, на разных устройствах
# Функция запуска бота
async def start_bot():
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)  # Убедимся, что нет конфликтов с вебхуками
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

# Функция для запуска бота в отдельном потоке
def run_bot():
    asyncio.run(start_bot())

def main():
    print("Введите ваш ID Telegram для запуска бота:")
    input_id = input("ID: ").strip()

    if input_id in user_ids:
        print(f"Бот запущен для пользователя с ID: {input_id}")

        bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_bot, daemon=True)
        bot_thread.start()

        bot_thread.join()
    else:
        print(f"Пользователь с ID {input_id} не имеет доступа!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

у меня код запускает бота, есть переменная user_ids (где хранятся ID людей, которые запускают бота, хранится в списке), при запуске кода на разных устройствах выбивает ошибка "ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher:Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = 7692442476)"
Написан бот на aiogram3, бот должен храниться локально на компьютере при запуске .exe (через Pyinstaller собираю)

" make sure that only one bot instance is running" - у вас несколько копий одного бота запущены на разных устройствах? Я так понимаю, бот может быть только один запущен.

А мне надо, чтобы запускалась копия на нескольких устройствах

@DmitryLesin бот (конкретный экземпляр) может быть запущен только один, Вам следует пересмотреть логику, которая требует "запуска копий на нескольких устройствах"

Это ограничение самого Телеграма. Ну зарегистрируйте несколько разных ID для бота, для каждой копии свой.
